# Windows Task Scheduler does not open Chrome browser as active window

Tags: google-chrome, windows-task-scheduler

I'm able to run chrome browser via Task Scheduler with arguments. But time to time chrome does not run as active windows. After one mouse click - window is active.

Is there any parameter or way to run chrome via Task Scheduler always as an active window?

I have set up time to wait after login for 20 seconds. May I try more?

Chrome is maximized, but main panel is visible and windows is not active.
After mouse-click window is active.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you mean that Chrome starts as minimized and you need to click the taskbar?

Comment: No no, it is maximized, but not active window.

Comment: It is orange blinking on the main panel.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found solution here. You just to run cmd and give /c start ... as arguments.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027931/task-scheduler-application-and-focus